# Having trouble with send and define_method

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I'm trying to create a custom attr_accessor, but can't seem to get it to work. Instead of returning the value assigned to the writer, it returns the instance variable.  Any ideas?

```
class Object
  def custom_attr_accessor(klass, attribute)
    ivar = "@#{attribute}".to_sym
    writer_body = lambda { |arg| instance_variable_set(ivar, arg) }
    reader_body = lambda { ivar }
    klass.send(:define_method, "#{attribute}=".to_sym, &writer_body) 
    klass.send(:define_method, "#{attribute}".to_sym, &reader_body)
  end
end

class Person
end

custom_attr_accessor(Person, :age)

me = Person.new
me.age = 100
puts me.age
```

=> @age

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like you did a `instance_variable_set`, you need `instance_variable_get`:

```
    reader_body = lambda { instance_variable_get(ivar) }
```

BTW, extending `Object` and passing a class is not very pretty. Try to make it `Persion. custom_attr_accessor(:age)`, that would be much more OOP.

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know about the get counterpart. I'm still confused why the instance variable is not returned when calling the getter method after being set via the writer method?  Thanks for the note on defining the custom_attr_accessor, but I'm just testing something. In practice, I'll set self by calling it from the current object.

Comment: `ivar` holds the name of your instance variable, not the value of the variable itself. Therefore the string of the variable name is returned.

Comment: Shouldn't that instance variable be evaluated when the method is called?

Comment: No, you would need at least `eval` or `instance_eval` for that. `instance_variable_get` is the specialized (and safer) method.